# Active route for multiple but similar routes in angular

Tags: angular

I have the below link item and i want it to be active for multiple links. Is that possible ?

```
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/testGame/list']"><i class="icon-game-controller"></i> baran</a>
  </li>
```

I want this link to be active for both links below

```
http://localhost:4200/#/testGame/crud

http://localhost:4200/#/testGame/list
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may define your routes like below,

```
{ path: 'testGame/:id', component: TestGameComponent }
```

now you may pass any param to the same route.

you can find detailed document on routing [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#overview).

**Update:**

you can write your own RouterLinkActive directive, which you can enhance to have any number of features,

Check this implementation in [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/GJSWSZmlk3WBNekUnsYK?p=preview)

```
@Input() startsWith: string = "";
  
private isLinkActive(router: Router): (link: (RouterLink|RouterLinkWithHref)) => boolean {
    return (link: RouterLink | RouterLinkWithHref) =>{
       if(!!this.startsWith){
          return router.url.indexOf(this.startsWith) > -1;
       }else{
        return  router.isActive(link.urlTree, this.routerLinkActiveOptions.exact);
       }
    }
  }
```

What I have done is simply copied the code from angular library and updated the part where route is being matched based upon some extra property,

```
<a customRouterLinkActive="active" routerLink="/testGame/crud" startsWith="testGame" >
 Crud
</a>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the routes. They are working fine. The problem is i want routerLinkActive="active" to work for both routes. It is only active for "testGame/list". I need some condition like startsWith="testGame"